# variance estimation using order statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, estimation, order-statistics, delta-method

I have four largest samples drawn from a distribution of N i.i.d Gaussian R.V. with standard deviation (Sigma) where sigma is unknown. N is known to be between 50-200. Mean is given to be 0.

1. How do we estimate Sigma (variance) using these 4 largest samples?
2. What is the error in the estimate?

Comment: if you had the min and the max, then you could use the range as an estimate of the variance. But, with just the largest, I have no clue. Hopefully someone else does.

Comment: By "4 largest samples" do you mean $X_{(n)}, X_{(n-1)}, X_{(n-2)}, X_{(n-3)}$ where $X_{(i)}$ is the $i$-th order statistic?

Answer (score 4):

If you know the sample size (as opposed to just knowing that the sample size is between 50 and 200), then maximum likelihood might work in this case.  Using *Mathematica*:

```
(* Joint distribution of largest 4 order statistics from a sample size of 100 *)
dist = OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]], 100}, {97, 98, 99, 100}];

(* Log of the likelihood *)
logL = Log[PDF[dist, {x97, x98, x99, x100}][[1, 1, 1]]];
```

[image: Log of likelihood]

This can be simplified a bit and upon removing additive constants we have

$$96\log \left(\Phi \left(\frac{x_{97}}{\sigma }\right)\right)-4 \log (\sigma )-\frac{x_{97}^2+x_{98}^2+x_{99}^2+x_{100}^2}{2 \sigma ^2}$$

where $\Phi(.)$ is the unit normal cdf.  We just find the value of $\sigma$ that maximizes the above equation.  In general if you just have the largest $k$ observations labeled $x_{n-k+1},x_{n-k},\ldots,x_n$ for a sample size of $n$, then the log of the likelihood is (excluding the additive constants):

$$(n-k)\log\left(\Phi\left(x_{n-k+1}/\sigma\right)\right)-k\log(\sigma)-{{1}\over{2\sigma^2}}\sum_{i=n-k+1}^n x_i^2$$

Note that this is highly dependent on being able to assume (as opposed to just being willing to assume) that the samples are all independent and from the same normal distribution with mean 0.  It's not often that happens.

```
(* Generate some data *)
SeedRandom[12345];
x = Sort[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];
data = {x97 -> x[[97]], x98 -> x[[98]], x99 -> x[[99]], x100 -> x[[100]]};

(* Obtain maximum likelihood estimate of \[Sigma] *)
mle = FindMaximum[{logL /. data, \[Sigma] > 0}, {{\[Mu], 0}, {\[Sigma], 1}}]
(* {2.00775, {\[Sigma] -> 0.931452}} *)

(* Estimated variance and standard error of the estimator of \[Sigma] *)
var\[Sigma] = -1/(D[logL /. data, {\[Sigma], 2}]) /. mle[[2]]
se\[Sigma] = var\[Sigma]^0.5
(* 0.110698 *)
```

**Addition**

If there are $s$ independent sets of samples of size $n_i$ where only the last $k_i$ observations are available (with $i=1,2,\ldots,s$), then one can sum the individual log likelihoods and maximize that function to get the maximum likelihood estimate:

$$\log{L}=-\frac{\sum _{i=1}^s \sum _{j=-k_i+n_i+1}^{n_i} x_{i,j}}{2 \sigma ^2}+\sum _{i=1}^s (n_i-k_i) \log \left(\Phi \left(\frac{x_{i,n_i-k_i+1}}{\sigma }\right)\right)-\log (\sigma ) \sum _{i=1}^s k_i$$

Then take the reciprocal of minus the second derivative of $\log{L}$ with respect to $\sigma$ and plug in $\hat{\sigma}$ for $\sigma$ to get an estimate of the variance.

While a symbolic representation of the estimated variance can be obtained, in practice that is probably not very useful.  Whatever optimization routine is used will likely produce something that will get you what you need.  Consider the single set of observations and the use of R:

```
# Generate some data
  n <- 100  # Sample size
  sigma <- 1
  set.seed(12345)
  x <- sigma*rnorm(n) # Normal with mean zero and sd sigma
# Now keep just the highest 4 values
  x <- x[order(x)][(n-3):n]

# Define log likelihood function
  logL <- function(sigma, n, x) {
    k <- length(x)
    (n-k)*log(pnorm(x[1]/sigma)) - k*log(sigma) - sum((x/sigma)^2)/2 
  }

# Find maximum likelihood estimate of sigma
# Using mean(x)/2 is a reasonable starting value when n=100
  result <- optim(mean(x)/2, logL, n=n, x=x, method="L-BFGS-B", 
    lower=0, upper=Inf, control=list(fnscale=-1), hessian=TRUE)
  result$par
  # 1.111482

# Now estimate the standard error
  se <- (-solve(result$hessian))^0.5
  se
  # 0.1376703
```

For multiple sets of data it depends on how you set up the data structure.  In the example below I put the information for each set of data in a separate list element.

```
# Generate some data
  nSets = 4 # Number of data sets
  n <- pmax(100,rpois(nSets, 150))  # Sample size
  k <- pmax(2, rpois(nSets, 5))     # Largest k observations available
  sigma <- 1
  set.seed(12345)
  y <- vector(mode = "list", length = nSets)  # Empty list
  for (i in 1:nSets) {
      y[[i]]$n <- n[i]
      x = sigma*rnorm(n[i]) # Normal with mean zero and sd sigma

      # Now keep just the highest k[i] values
      x <- x[order(x)][(n[i]-k[i]+1):n[i]]
      y[[i]]$x <- x
  }
  
# Define log likelihood function
  logL <- function(sigma, n, x) {
    k <- length(x)
    (n-k)*log(pnorm(x[1]/sigma)) - k*log(sigma) - sum((x/sigma)^2)/2 
  }

# Define sum of log likelihood functions
  sumlogL <- function(sigma, y) {
    s = 0
    for (i in 1:length(y)) {
        s = s + logL(sigma, y[[i]]$n, y[[i]]$x)
    }
    s
  }
    
# Find maximum likelihood estimate of sigma
  result <- optim(mean(y[[1]]$x)/2, sumlogL, y=y, method="L-BFGS-B", 
    lower=0, upper=Inf, control=list(fnscale=-1), hessian=TRUE)
  result$par
  # 1.058365

# Now estimate the standard error
  se <- (-solve(result$hessian))^0.5
  se
  # 0.05002775
```

Alternatively if the $k_i$ are all equal and the $n_i$ are close to being equal, then just take the mean of the individual estimates and use the usual formula for a sample standard deviation to obtain an estimate of $\sigma$.

Comment: Thankyou for the code. Really helpful. I just need to understand how the "log of likelihood" is calculated above.
            logL = Log[PDF[dist, {x97, x98, x99, x100}][[1, 1, 1]]] 

What is the significance of [1,1,1] in the above line? Do you know of any reference which describes/derives this equation? Thankyou

Comment: Sorry.  I just had time yesterday to put in the *Mathematica* code.  Later today I'll update my answer with more standard notation.  Also, for understanding the code, just ignore the '[[1,1,1]]`.  The PDF from *Mathematica* has several pieces and the formula for the pdf equation is just indexed that way.

Comment: Thanks Jim. There is one last part to this. What if we have multiple draws from the same distribution, with each draw y = four largest samples, but now we observe y_1, y_2 etc. How will the variance estimation change?

Answer (score 1):

Comment: This the germ of an idea, not yet a solution. [I am assuming the mean $\mu$ is also unknown.]

Suppose $n = 100$ observations from a standard normal distribution.
You might find the distance $D$ between order statistics 97 and 100.
Then $1/D$ should estimate $1.$ Several runs give various answers. In R,

```
set.seed(123)
diff(sort(rnorm(100))[c(97,100)])
[1] 0.4004199
diff(sort(rnorm(100))[c(97,100)])
[1] 1.243827
diff(sort(rnorm(100))[c(97,100)])
[1] 0.337785
diff(sort(rnorm(100))[c(97,100)])
[1] 0.8870224
```

Find the average of a million runs:

```
set.seed(2021)
d.4 = replicate(10^6, diff( sort(rnorm(100))[c(97,100)] ) )
mean(d.4)
[1] 0.7060959

sg.est = d.4/.706
mean(sg.est);  sd(sg.est)
[1] 1.000136
[1] 0.5530556
```

So, on average the distance between the 97th and 100th order statistics
divided by 0.706 estimates $\sigma$ with standard error about 0.553.

Here is a histogram of such estimates of $\sigma$ along with quantiles 0.025 and 0.975
of the estimates.

[image]

```
hist(d.4/.706, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v=quantile(sg.est, c(.975,.025)), col="red")
```

Maybe we can find normal quantiles that give approximately 0.706, without
simulation. One possibility:

```
diff(qnorm(c(.97,.995)))
[1] 0.6950357
```

Something like this might generalize for other values of $n$ between 50 and 200.